# Rails Rake Task - How to Delete Records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

I am trying to use a daily RAKE task to synchronize a users table in my app with a CSV file.

My import.rake task successfully imports records that aren't found in the table (find_or_create_by_username), but I don't know how to delete records from the table that are no longer found in the CSV file.  What should I use instead of "find_or_create_by_username" to achieve this?  Thanks in advance.

```
  #lib/tasks/import.rake

  desc "Import employees from csv file"
  task :import => [:environment] do

  file = "db/testusers.csv"

usernames = [] # make an array to collect names
CSV.foreach(file, headers: true) do |row|
    Employee.find_or_create_by_username({
      # Add this line:
      username = row[0]
      :username => username,
      :last_name => row[1],
      :first_name => row[2],
      :employee_number => row[3],
      :phone => row[4],
      :mail_station => row[5]
    }
    )
    # Collect the usernames
    usernames << username
    end
# Delete the employees (make sure you fire them first)
Employee.where.not( username: usernames ).destroy_all
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by doing like the following:

```
#lib/tasks/import.rake
require 'csv'

desc "Import employees from csv file"
task :import => [:environment] do

    file = "db/users.csv"
    employee_ids_to_keep = []

    CSV.foreach(file, headers: true) do |row|
      attrs = {
        :username => row[0], :last_name => row[1], :first_name => row[2], 
        :employee_number => row[3], :phone => row[4],:mail_station => row[5]
      }
      # retrieves the Employee with username
      employee = Employee.where(username: attrs[:username]).first

      if employee.present? # updates the user's attributes if exists
        employee.update_attributes(attrs)
      else # creates the Employee if does not exist in the DB
        employee = Employee.create!(attrs)
      end

      # keeps the ID of the employee to not destroy it
      employee_ids_to_keep << employee.id 
    end

    Employee.where('employees.id NOT IN (?)', employee_ids_to_keep).destroy_all
end
```

Comment: This worked great after I removed validations from the Employee model.  It was complaining about a blank first_name, even though the CSV file had no blank first_names, so I don't know why, but I will work through that.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Get a list of all ID's in the database and store them in a set.  Then as you do your importing, remove valid employees from the set.  Once you're done, any ID's left in the set need to be removed from the database.

Something like this...

```
existing_ids = Employee.pluck(:id).to_set
CSV.foreach(file, headers: true) do |row|
  employee = Employee.find_or_create_by.....
  existing_ids.delete(employee.id)
end     
Employee.destroy(*existing_ids.to_a) unless existing_ids.empty?
```

Comment: I tried this but something isn't right - it aborts the rake and says it `can't find Employee with id = [the next-generated auto increment number that is no longer in the table]`  I'll try the other answers and/or tweak this one - it's in the right direction. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
usernames = [] # make an array to collect names
CSV.foreach(file, headers: true) do |row|
    username = row[0]
    Employee.find_or_create_by_username({
      :username => username,
      :last_name => row[1],
      :first_name => row[2],
      :employee_number => row[3],
      :phone => row[4],
      :mail_station => row[5]
    }
    )
    # Collect the usernames
    usernames << username
    end
# Delete the employees (make sure you fire them first)
Employee.where.not( username: usernames ).destroy_all
```

`where.not` will work with rails 4 of course.

Comment: This will destroy all the employees contained in the CSV, we want the opposite

Comment: calling `.delete_all` will not passes through the dependencies to check if the related object should be destroyed or not: its very brutal. `.destroy_all` does not bypass these "callbacks": safer.

Comment: Thanks all. I'm getting a syntax error `/lib/tasks/import.rake:12: syntax error, unexpected '\n', expecting tASSOC` , where line 12 is: `username = row[0]`  I've updated my original post with your changes to make sure I copied correctly. (And I am using Rails 4, btw)

Comment: Sorry, moved location of the -- username = row[0] -- line. Look at the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks, getting closer.  Now I'm getting:  `rake aborted! wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)...../active_record/relation/query_methods.rb:132:in 'where'`

Comment: Are you positive you're using rails 4? Try doing 'rails -v' and see what it relates back to you. Otherwise you might try Employee.where("username not in (?)", usernames).destroy_all